# construction links between a timesheet database and a document database

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2010

I currently have a document database and a timesheet database.

Users book by generic "workpacks" that encapsulate multiple documents.
The current system that distributes hours booked to the "burnt hours" field of the document database.

The algorithm sums the hours to a "workpack" and divides it amongst the documents in the "workpack". this means the data on the origins of the hours, who and when is lost.

The document database is a table with a row per document each document has a unique ID. Each document has a "percent complete" and "burnt hours"

The timesheet database logs hours by user and "workpack" these then have to be distributed to the documents. Whilst the hours are currently evenly spread across documents in the "workpack" I want to adjust the algorithm to send hours just to documents that gain "percent complete" over a timeperiod as well.

How would you go about adjusting it so that I can see who's hours has gone to a document through it's existence? Documents may move "workpacks" through it's existance.

Would I need to break it up into a table per document? I have about 7000 documents and 100+ users.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

It can reside in either database, but is probably best put in the database that assigns the hours. I would suggest:

```
DocumentID )
UserID     ) Primary key
Timestamp  )
BurntHours
```

Do not create a table for each document.